# why when use listView some controls in page disappeared?

Tags: c#, xaml, xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android

I use `SearchBar` to search from `listView` and I have other controls
but when page load just `SearchBar` appear and other controls disappear
like this image

[image]

and when search then select from `listView` the disappeared controls appears

like this image
[image]
[image]

my xaml code :

```
<StackLayout>
                <SearchBar x:Name="search_trade" 
                       TextChanged="search_trade_TextChanged"
                       />
                <ListView x:Name="list" ItemSelected="list_ItemSelected" >
                    <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate>
                            <TextCell Text="{Binding Name}" ></TextCell>
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </ListView.ItemTemplate>
                </ListView>
                <Editor x:Name="edit_trade"
                    FontSize="14"/>
            </StackLayout>
```

my c# code :

```
private void search_trade_TextChanged(object sender, TextChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (search_trade.Text.Trim()==string.Empty)
        {
            list.IsVisible = false;
        }
        list.IsVisible = true;
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(e.NewTextValue))
        {
            list.ItemsSource = tempdata;
        }

        else
        {
            list.ItemsSource = tempdata.Where(x => x.Name.ToLower().StartsWith(e.NewTextValue));
        }
    }
    private void list_ItemSelected(object sender, SelectedItemChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        var item = (Contacts)e.SelectedItem;
        edit_trade.Text = item.Name.ToString();
        search_trade.Text = "";
        list.IsVisible = false;
        edit_trade.IsReadOnly = true;
    }
```

code c# that I initially set the ItemsSource :

```
public Anti_biotic()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        active();
        years_months();
        frame_view.IsVisible = false;
        trade();
    }
    private void trade()
    {
        tempdata = new List<Contacts>
        {
            new Contacts() { Name = "Amoclawin228.5mg/5mlsusp60ml"},
            new Contacts() { Name = "Amoclawin 457mg / 5ml susp 60 ml"},
            new Contacts() { Name = "Amoflux 250 mg susp 100 ml"},
};
}
```

how can I solve this issue?

Comment: are you setting the ListView ItemsSource on page load?

Comment: @Jason yes I fill `ListView` on `InitializeComponent();`

Comment: the two most obvious reasons would be if IsVIsible is false or if the ListView does not contain any data.  Can you post the code where you initially set the ItemsSource?

Comment: I make `ListView` IsVIsible=false and when text changed in `SearchBar ` `ListView` IsVIsible=true, and I will put code that I initially set the ItemsSource in my main post.

Comment: `trade()` initializes `tempdata` but does not assign `ItemsSource`

Comment: @Jason I'm sorry I'm a beginner so I can't understand you, could you explain?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you are not assigning the `ListView`'s `ItemsSource` when the page loads.  If the `ListView` doesn't have any data then it won't display anything

```
public Anti_biotic()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    active();
    years_months();
    frame_view.IsVisible = false;

    // this method creates tempdata but doesn't do anything with it
    trade();

    // add this
    list.ItemsSource = tempdata;
}
```

Comment: thank you it worked, but all data have the same name (pedi_dose_App.Anti_biotic+Contacts)

Comment: does your data have a `Name` property?  That is what you are using for the TextCell binding